# What is the problem with the format specifier C++

Tags: c++, scanf, format-specifiers

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    float b = 323.23f;
    std::scanf("%6.3f\n", &b);  // <-- Warning
    std::printf("%6.3f\n", b);
}
```

There is a warning at `scanf()` stating:

> Invalid conversion specifier `'.'`

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `%6.3f` with `printf`, the `.3` specifies the precision of the output.

`scanf` doesn't need you to specify the precision, because it will accept whatever precision it finds in the input stream. So you aren't allowed to specify `.3` (or `.`-anything-else) in a `scanf` format. Just use `%6f` or even `%f` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier for `scanf` doesn't require you to explicitly specify the number of places after the decimal point. Plus, it is what is causing the warning, it is better off to use just a plain `%f` inside the `scanf` though a `%6f` also works.

This isn't the case with the `printf` though. When you use a `[some_number].[number_of_places]f`, like, for example, `6.3f` in a `printf`, while the `.3f` would affect the number of places after the decimal point which would be displayed, the `6` in it reserves that many character spaces to display the entire number.

Hope this helps to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier in C does not take the value '6.3'.You can use '%6f' or simply '%f'. '%6.3f' is the thing that is causing the warning.